# Error in react-native-navigation after updating MainApplication.java

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I installed react native navigation and followed the steps. Works on iOS. Doesn't on android. 
I get this error when I run react-native run-android, after updating "MainApplication.java" file:

> > Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
>
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
>   incompatible with G radle 6.0. Use '--warning-mode all' to show the
>   individual deprecation warnings. See
>   https://docs.gradle.org/5.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
>   43 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 41 up-to-date
>   /home/wilux/rnApp/android/app/src/main/java/com/rnApp/MainApplication.java:
>   17: error: MainApplication is not abstract and does not override
>   abstract method  createAdditionalReactPackages() in
>   NavigationApplication public class MainApplication extends
>   NavigationApplication {
>          ^ 1 error
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
>   > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 4s
>
> error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android
>   development environment set up:
>   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment.
>   Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details. Error: Command failed:
>   ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
>   /home/wilux/rnApp/android/app/src/main/java/com/rnApp/MainApplication.java:17:
>   error: MainApplication is not abstract and does not override abstract
>   method createAdditionalReactPackages() in NavigationApplication public
>   class MainApplication extends NavigationApplication {
>          ^ 1 error
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
>   > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 4s
>
> ```
> at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:610:11)
> at execFileSync (child_process.js:628:15)
> at runOnAllDevices (/home/wilux/rnApp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:94:39)
> at buildAndRun (/home/wilux/rnApp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:158:41)
> at /home/wilux/rnApp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:125:12
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
> at async Command.handleAction (/home/wilux/rnApp/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:164:9)
> ```

The strange thing is that it worked when I update "android/build.gradle" and "android/app/build.gradle" files !

Here is the updated file (MainApplication.java) :

```js
package com.rnApp;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationApplication;
import com.reactnativenavigation.react.NavigationReactNativeHost;
import com.reactnativenavigation.react.ReactGateway;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends NavigationApplication {
    
        @Override
        protected ReactGateway createReactGateway() {
            ReactNativeHost host = new NavigationReactNativeHost(this, isDebug(), createAdditionalReactPackages()) {
                @Override
                protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
                    return "index";
                }
            };
            return new ReactGateway(this, isDebug(), host);
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean isDebug() {
            return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }
    
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
            // Add additional packages you require here
            // No need to add RnnPackage and MainReactPackage
            return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
                // eg. new VectorIconsPackage()
            );
        }
    
        @Override
        public List<ReactPackage> createAdditionalReactPackages() {
            return getPackages();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Provide some more logs, it can help us to debug it or to get exact error.

Comment: done. I must also clarify that I followed the steps from this link : https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/Installing?id=_7-update-mainapplicationjava

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a stab in the dark but for me, 90% of android build problems (especially when you've been modifying native files) can be fixed by executing the gradle clean task by either:

1. Changing into the android directory of your project (`cd android`)
2. Running gradlew clean (Windows: `.\gradlew.bat clean` OSX/Linux: `./gradlew clean`)
3. Attempt to rebuild